# In Harry Potter, why don't werewolves Apparate to the other side of the Earth for a couple of days so that they won't transform?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, magical-transportation

From what I remember, Apparation can transport you fairly long distances.  And if that's too dangerous for unskilled wizards, why don't they just set up a chain of Portkeys?

Edit: I am aware that the full moon happens across all of Earth, but I thought it was only nighttime that werewolves transform.

Comment: Taking a potion is easier?

Comment: Werewolves are shunned by wizarding society. Who exactly is going to set up a chain of Portkeys for them?

Comment: When the moon is full, it's full for the entire Earth.  Unless you expect the werewolves to keep teleporting around so they're always in sunlight away from moonbeams, but then they wouldn't get any sleep.

Comment: I think that in light of what @jwodder points out, this is off-topic as a "question seeking scientific explanations"... Since the question is essentially asking why you can't avoid the full moon by traveling around the world.

Comment: Bellerophon, Wolfsbane is a pretty advanced potion, but then again Hermione brewed Polyjuice in her first year so idk.

Comment: jwodder I phrased that badly, but I don't see how they would get tired. Heres what i was thinking, 5pmish, teleport somehow to where its 8am or so, then sleep for 10 hours, then teleport again. Do that for a couple of days until its not full moon

Comment: I think that Bristish kids wouldn't really say that the prospect of being bitten by an Australian werewolf rather than a British one (and vice versa) was really solving the problem.

Comment: @ThePyjamasTerror You mean her second year.

Comment: @Pryftan Yup, mixed em up

Comment: @ThePyjamasTerror Easy enough to do. And even if it is only one year more it's still pretty impressive what she was able to do because it's noted that Polyjuice Potion is difficult to get right and can go badly wrong; the fact it backfired on her is only because she had the wrong type of hair but I got the impression it's difficult to brew anyway. So what's the difference between a first year and a second year? Probably not much for such an advanced potion!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### They would need a network of Portkeys, requiring a lot of inter-Ministry support.

If werewolves were to keep traveling to avoid the nighttime in any country, they'd need a network of Portkeys spanning the entire globe. Setting up such a network would require the cooperation of various Ministries of Magic around the world: it's unlikely that one single Ministry of Magic could set something like this up for the werewolves in their country without the approval of others.

In addition, the Ministry of Magic in Britain is prejudiced against werewolves, so at least as the Ministry is over the course of the series, it's unlikely they'd be willing to make the effort to attempt to set up a global network of Portkeys for werewolves to avoid the nighttime.

#### Also, it might not work - it's unclear whether werewolves only transform at night.

There isn't anything indicating whether werewolves transform only at night, or if once the moon is full, they remain transformed until the moon begins to wane again. Traveling around the world would only work if the transformation was triggered every night by the sunset and subsequent rising of the moon. If, however, once it's a full moon they remain transformed until the phase of the moon changes, then they'd still transform wherever they are.

Lupin mentions disappearing once a month, but it isn't clear whether his absence during the day is because he's still transformed into a werewolf, or because having transformed the night before left him feeling weak and needing to rest.

What little evidence there is seems to imply that the transformation lasts, night and day, until the moon wanes again.

> “As long as I take it in the week preceding the full moon, I keep my mind when I transform … I am able to curl up in my office, a harmless wolf, and wait for the moon to wane again.” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 18 (Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs)</sup></sub>

In addition, every time Lupin or someone else refers to his transformation, they say it's "once a month", not "nightly", and there doesn't seem to be any evidence he turns back human during the day. He never mentioned doing anything as a human during the day when the moon is full, even in a weakened state.

Answer (score 12):

When the moon is full, it is [full for the entire Earth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20947/is-the-full-moon-full-everywhere-on-the-planet).

In some places, the full moon is even visible during the day.

No matter where they apparated, they would still be under a full moon.

Of course, it depends on how the full moon thing works; if they transform only at night, then they could go to Antarctica or the Arctic, whichever is currently experiencing 24-hour daylight.

Without more information on how the magic of Werewolves works and what actually causes the transformation, then the answer to your question is: nowhere on Earth is safe.

Comment: Iirc in the non canon movie Remus didnt transform until the moon was directly visible.

Comment: @JohnP Yes but he would still transform inside the shrieking shack, Hogwarts and other buildings such as his house. So as long as the moon is full, they transform

Comment: @MikasaPinata Agreed, but why then does Lupin only transform once the moon appears from behind the clouds? Shouldn't he have transformed the moment the full moon arose over the horizon? Is it the existence of the *full **moon*** that transforms them (then they should be transformed all the time, since the moon is full [as in completely there] all the time after all, just not fully *visible*) or is it the *moon**light** of the full moon*, at which point staying inside, in complete darkness, in a cave or a dungeon should be sufficient to prevent transformation, which most likely isnt the case.

Comment: @BMWurm There are two possible answers to that: 1) the film producers (or whomever decides that) feel the need to change things (often with Riddikulus excuses although sometimes they are valid); or 2) the full moon really only started at that exact moment. Choose your potion. I personally feel it's 1 (and I don't even think the logic behind 2 is valid) but I have a real problem with the way films mutilate stories (not to say I can't enjoy films but I also see the book in my mind when I'm watching it so I just filter).

Comment: @JohnP Yes indeed that's correct. But as you point out it's not canon. And I'll just keep it at that because you say it far nicer than I've ever managed (or at least I usually don't manage?).

Comment: @BMWurm But otoh as far as logic 2 goes: maybe it is possible because in the book it's also outside the shack. So maybe there is a a third possibility? That either Rowling didn't think that through or she truly meant it that way: that it only happened right then at that moment?

Comment: @Pryftan - Hah! :) I'm less of a purist than some.

Comment: @JohnP Probably best for your own sanity anyway. I don't know though; I mean I can still appreciate and enjoy the effects etc. of the film. I just find some changes entirely inexcusable and rather disgraceful. This change in particular - if it is indeed a change (as I noted it seems to be consistent with the book but whether or not it's because the moon only shows itself is another matter; don't recall that from the book) - isn't all that bad (and I suppose was done for effect).